# Update cocoapods to desired version

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

We use cocoapods IQKeyboardManagerSwift in our project but IQKeyboardManagerSwift has updated Swift 3.0 to version `4.0.6`. In the pod file, I wrote:

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' , '~> 4.0.5'
```

Then,  after installation , I found that it is still version `4.0.6`

Comment: use pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '4.0.6'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below asks for version `4.0.5` **or greater**

```
'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '~> 4.0.5'
```

and this line asks for version  `4.0.5` **exactly**

```
'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '4.0.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, just updated and tested yesterday.

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```