# Firebase Invalid bitcode version

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2

Is it possible to Archive a project that using some Firebase SDKs using xcode v7.3.1 ? I tried so but got this `Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '800.0.38.0_0' Reader: '703.0.31_0')`

```
pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'
pod 'FirebaseDatabase'
pod 'FirebaseCore'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
pod 'FirebaseCrash'
```

The problem is Firebase depends on `GoogleUtilities` which is build in xcode v8.x if I am not mistaken

Comment: Maybe try to specify an older version of Firebase, then `pod install` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658862/update-cocoapods-to-desired-version/39659014#39659014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above error came out and perform the Archive for app application

The workaround is as follows 
the Build Settings> Enable `Bitcode` to `NO`

Disabling ENABLE `BITCODE` does not have any adverse effect on product archive. Since this is an optional flag for Apple, so you can disable it unless Apple makes it required flag in the future. For more details, you can refer to Bitcode [Enabling/Disabling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no)

Comment: I was trying to avoid using this but it seems impossible to build without it.

Comment: @Bobj-C, how did you make it?still bit code enable to no? I was having the same thing on Xcode 7.3.1